# How do I "trim" my array of strings?

Tags: arrays, ruby, trim

With Ruby, I'm curious about how to remove the leading and ending elements of an array of strings if those elements are blank (either `nil` or the empty string).  If I have an array of

```
["", "a", "", "b", nil, ""]
```

I would want the result to be

```
["a", "", "b"]
```

I found a partial way to remove the right non-present elements of an array using

```
arr.pop until arr.last || arr.empty?
```

But that seems to only work with trimming the `nil` elements of the end of my array.  It doesn't address empty strings or removing the blank elements from the front of an array.

Comment: This sounds like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". I'd recommend showing what is generating the arrays as it sounds like that should be what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.
 drop_while { |element| element.nil? || element.empty? }.
 reverse.
 drop_while { |element| element.nil? || element.empty? }.
 reverse
```

If you want to remove the repetition:

```
blank = ->(element) { element.nil? || element.empty? }

array.drop_while(&blank).reverse.drop_while(&blank).reverse
```

---

If you are using active support, you can do it directly:

```
array.drop_while(&:blank?).reverse.drop_while(&:blank?).reverse
```

Comment: `array.drop_while(&blank).reverse_each.drop_while(&blank)` is slightly better IMO

Comment: @steenslag, why is what you suggest better?

Comment: @steenslag, I forgot it exists (:

Comment: @Natalia, with it you are not actually reversing the array. You just traverse it in reversed order.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sort of clunky solution that involves testing the first element and removing it with `shift`, while doing the same with the last and `pop`:

```
list = [nil, "", "a", "", "b", nil, "", nil]

while ((!list.first or !list.first.match(/\S/)) and list.any?)
  list.shift
end

while ((!list.last or !list.last.match(/\S/)) and list.any?)
  list.pop
end

list
# => ["a", "", "b"]
```

Remember that empty strings are still logically true in Ruby, as anything that isn't literally `nil` or `false` will be. If you're in Ruby on Rails or are using ActiveSupport you'll have access to the `.present?` method which is a more rigorous test, requiring the string to be defined and contain at least one non-space character.

Answer (score 0):

```
ndx = array.index { |e| !e.to_s.empty? }
array[ndx..array.rindex { |e| !e.to_s.empty? }] unless ndx.nil?
  #=> ["a", "", "b"]
```

If `e #=> nil`, `e.to_s #=> ''`.

Comment: Just an FYI if the array is [], the above gives an error.

Comment: Good point. It was also a problem if the array contains nothing other than `nil` and `''`. I fixed it.